# Why is this line a valid typescript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Why is this line a valid typescript code?

`import ManagerRoleEnum = ManagerBean.ManagerRoleEnum`

ManagerBean is a namespace generated by Swagger that looks like this:

```
export namespace ManagerBean {
    /**
     * @export
     * @enum {string}
     */
    export enum ManagerRoleEnum {
        PRIMARY = <any> 'MANAGER_PRIMARY',
        SECONDARY = <any> 'MANAGER_SECONDARY'
    }
}
```

IDEA automatically imports enums like this instead of

```
import { ManagerBean } from './api.ts'
const ManagerRoleEnum = { ManagerBean }
```

I am trying to understand why this is a valid code in order to forbid this behaviour with ESLint. Please help

Comment: `import ___ = ___` is a way to alias a namespace member or import a CJS module.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `import _ = _` and `export = _` are described in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) as a way import/export CommonJS or AMD modules.

However, `import _ = _` has the additional use of aliasing a namespace member. Took me a while, but I found the relevant [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases) for this feature.

> **Not to be confused with the import x = require("name") syntax** used to load modules, this syntax simply creates an alias for the specified symbol. You can use these sorts of imports (commonly referred to as aliases) for any kind of identifier, including objects created from module imports.

```
namespace AReallyLongNamespaceName {
  export const theOnlyThingINeed = 42;
}

import theAnswer = AReallyLongNamespaceName.theOnlyThingINeed;

console.log(theAnswer); // 42
```

This is the ONLY way to alias a namespace member.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBAShEAbLBPAMgPbADmAcuNHIhZEgN4BQSSEAHjIQE4AuS8xKHx4ALCAHlgeACoiAlqQCSZCBAAmSALxIALACYA3IwC+jRnLCdeSURBTAoAdwhctqDNjxFStKggi+AHS2kjLySirqRowCDoRYEIFYhCQAFLb2Ti4AlAZAA)

As for the ESLint rule to disable this syntax, I don't think there is any yet.